# Does Nexus 3 support container image signing?

Tags: docker, containers, nexus, rhel, signing

Does Nexus 3 private docker registry support container image signing?  The [RHEL documentation here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/managing_containers/signing_container_images) suggests not, but I'd like confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

In the sense that Nexus supports the v2 Registry API, it should be able to handle signed images. I don't believe Nexus supplies a [Notary](https://github.com/docker/notary) service though which is where most of the signing operations occur and image/key information is stored. The [Nexus docco](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Private+Registry+for+Docker) mentions nothing about signing.

You can [delegate trust](https://docs.master.dockerproject.org/engine/security/trust/trust_delegation/) for your Nexus repo to a local [Notary service](https://docs.master.dockerproject.org/engine/security/trust/deploying_notary/) ([github](https://github.com/docker/notary/blob/master/docs/running_a_service.md)) as you would for any private repo. Nexus repo's have a habit of tripping over edge cases though.